# Is it possible to specify the scala compiler used by sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I modified the source code of scala compiler and built it. Now I want to test this compiler. However, many existing scala projects use sbt as build tool. So I wonder if it is possible to replace the official scala compiler used by sbt with the scala compiler built by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Configuring-Scala.html#Using+Scala+from+a+local+directory:

> The result of building Scala from source is a Scala home directory `<base>/build/pack/` that contains a subdirectory `lib/` containing the Scala library, compiler, and other jars. The same directory layout is obtained by downloading and extracting a Scala distribution. Such a Scala home directory may be used as the source for jars by setting scalaHome. For example,
>
> ```
> scalaHome := Some(file("/home/user/scala-2.10/"))
> ```

If you want to `publish` the compiler, use @ipoteka's answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I found that i should set scalaHome := Some(file("/home/user/scala-2.10/build/pack")).    :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Configuring-Scala.html) it's straightforward:

```
managedScalaInstance := false

libraryDependencies += "yourPackage" % "yourScalaCompiler" % version
```

Don't forget to `publish-local` you compiler first.

Comment: According to the docs, this snippet won't work (dependency is for the wrong configuration, no scala-library dependency, `"yourScalaCompiler"` must be `"scala-compiler"`). Use the one given there instead.